# Open Source Reputation System for a Wiki

Tags: open-source, wikipedia

I am playing around with the idea of starting a specialized [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wiki). I think having a reputation system would greatly increase the user's motivation on such a site. The [original wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page) does indeed have a [reputation system](http://portal.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1242608) but it is not comparable to the one used on the stackexchange network.

Hence my question:

> #### Is there an open-source reputation system for Wiki's like the one used at stackexchange?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMHO it is very hard to calculate reputation for a real Wiki in the SO-way. If you let the users vote for articles, how you distribute this reputation amongst the editors? After the count of edits? After the amount of added bytes? Both variants could be played to gain more reputation, and that wouldn't improve the article. That's why I would be very careful about that.

Comment: Thank you for your thoughts. I agree that measuring the reputation of everyone's contribution is hard on a wiki. The point is that I thought that somebody has done a good job already thinking about such things - I am not the guy able to implement it myself :) Greets

Answer (score 1):

The authors of that paper contributed work to the [WikiTrust](http://wikitrust.soe.ucsc.edu/) project. While it is not "SO" like in function, it's "batch mode" seems like it might be helpful. It demonstrates extraction of detailed author history for an article. Using WikiTrust in "online mode" would add reputation coding to all the pages.